# How do you paint in 2.8’s UV editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

I’m trying to put a black dot right in the middle of this sphere, but  nothing appears when I click down on my map. Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Not sure, probs need to share your blend file. But you can try follow this tutorial for beginners on texture paint might give you some clues to what your problem is: https://youtu.be/vTYustK-XBk

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the texture is in your material graph.

Select the texture slot in the active tool settings.

Start paint.

[image]

Comment: Where do I select it in my active tool settings?

Comment: Updated the answer